# Java installers for Windows and Mac

Tags: java, windows, macos, installation

Would like to know which library (open source preferable) should I use to create a desktop app self installer. It should have the below features

1. Can create installer for both Windows and Mac
2. We should be able to bundle the JRE along with it
   Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to look at [IzPack](http://izpack.org/) which has powerful features and the advantages to be free.

Comment: does it meet both the requirements

Comment: Yes, grom what i remember it does. You can find a tutorial for izpack here: http://www.softwarepassion.com/deploy-your-java-application-with-izpack-installer/

Comment: Yes you're it does, both are fulfilled, plus an excellent integration with maven, and a dynamic community. Easy to configure, with an XML descriptive language to autogenerate relevant panels and i18n

Answer (score 0):

not open source but [installAnywhere](http://www.flexerasoftware.com) is a good package.

Answer (score 0):

Install4j is yet another important library to be mentioned here